# How Excessive masturbation can make a person unfit for army?

Tags: sex, sexual-reproduction

Recently I saw this [news](http://www.news18.com/news/world/excessive-masturbation-is-chinese-armys-latest-headache-1501813.html) trending, I never heard single 
disadvantage regarding masturbation.

But China Army considering it has danger for army.
So How Excessive masturbation can make a person unfit for army?

Comment: Maybe don't get your medical advice from the Chinese army.

Comment: Maybe step back a bit, and ask just what's an enlarged testicular vein, how it's detected, and (if such a thing actually exists) whether it is indeed caused by "excessive" masturbation?  Or maybe consider that it's just ignorant prejudice, like the Western ban on homosexuals that existed until fairly recently.

Comment: Well, using some common sense I'm pretty sure the reason is that a soldier who is busy masturbating won't be a good soldier. It's the same with any kind of addiction, causing the person to not perform the tasks they're supposed to do.